# Javascript don't updating randomElement()

Tags: javascript, random

I'm trying to get a random election of an image in javascript, and it works, but when I click a button and the image changes, `randomElement` still being the same as the first time it worked. I'm trying to update it using the same name for another random election, but isn't working. Here is the code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
const catbutton=document.getElementById('catbutton')
const cubebutton=document.getElementById('cubebutton')
const image=document.getElementById('image')
var x=0
var arr= ["pr1.jpg", "pr2.jpg"]
const randomElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
console.log(randomElement)
image.src=(randomElement);
catbutton.onclick=function() {catfunction()};
function catfunction(){
    if (randomElement=="pr1.jpg"){
        x++;
        alert(x)
        const randomElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
        console.log(randomElement)
        image.src=(randomElement);
    }
    else if (randomElement=="pr2.jpg"){
        alert("Fallaste!")
    }
}
cubebutton.onclick=function() {cubefunction()};
function cubefunction(){
    if (randomElement=="pr2.jpg"){
        x++;
        alert(x)
        const randomElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
        console.log(randomElement)
        image.src=(randomElement);
    }
    else if (randomElement=="pr1.jpg"){
        alert("Fallaste!")
    }
}
})
```

Comment: You've three different declarations of `const randomElement`.  Which one do you expect to update?  Might you want to change the top `const randomElement` to `let randomElement` and get rid of the `const` on your functions so that they just assign to the outer declaration?

Comment: @MikeSamuel Yes, I want to change the top one. By the way, I'm new in javascript

Comment: @MikeSamuel But I still don't know how to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
if (randomElement=="pr1.jpg"){
    x++;
    alert(x)
    const randomElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
    console.log(randomElement)
    image.src=(randomElement);
}
```

the

```
const randomElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
```

is a [const declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) that has no effect on other declarations with the same name.

See ["JavaScript: Introduction to Scope (function scope, block scope)"](https://dev.to/sandy8111112004/javascript-introduction-to-scope-function-scope-block-scope-d11) for an explanation of *block scope*.

If you remove the `const` keyword, it becomes

```
if (randomElement=="pr1.jpg"){
    x++;
    alert(x)
    randomElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
    console.log(randomElement)
    image.src=(randomElement);
}
```

which assigns to the `randomElement` declared here:

```
const randomElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
```

You'll then run into a problem because you can only assign a `const` declaration once.  You should change that to a `let` declaration which will allow you to assign new values when the button handlers run.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
const catbutton=document.getElementById('catbutton')
const cubebutton=document.getElementById('cubebutton')
const image=document.getElementById('image')
var x=0
var arr= ["pr1.jpg", "pr2.jpg"]
let randomElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
console.log(randomElement)
image.src=(randomElement);
catbutton.onclick=function() {catfunction()};
function catfunction(){
    if (randomElement=="pr1.jpg"){
        x++;
        alert(x)
        randomElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
        console.log(randomElement)
        image.src=(randomElement);
    }
    else if (randomElement=="pr2.jpg"){
        alert("Fallaste!")
    }
}
cubebutton.onclick=function() {cubefunction()};
function cubefunction(){
    if (randomElement=="pr2.jpg"){
        x++;
        alert(x)
        randomElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
        console.log(randomElement)
        image.src=(randomElement);
    }
    else if (randomElement=="pr1.jpg"){
        alert("Fallaste!")
    }
}
})
```